# Striped color override in bootstrap is not working for I.E. 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen several questions talk on this and make recommendations. I'm simply trying to make the alternatiing rows in Bootstrap (2.3.2) appear darker in I.E. 8. I've tried overriding the style with a notably darker background color:

```
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  background-color: #BFBABA;  
}
```

I've cleared my I.E. 8 browser cache; closed it and re-opened, and yet nothing I change for this style seems to take effect. I've styled my table with the following:

```
table table-bordered table-striped
```

Notably and predictably, the changes work in Chrome just fine.

Does anyone have any thoughts or possible work arounds here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of `nth-child()` is not supported by IE8 and down.

It is, however, supported by IE9, IE10 and all other, current browsers.

**See http://caniuse.com/css-sel3**

You will have to take another approach to overwrite the properties if you want it to work in IE8 <

Comment: Go figure. Thanks for the detailed link. Now I know at least.

Comment: @jason You can suggest to those users to upgrade to a real browser, or at least use the most recent version of the crappy browser they like to use :P

Comment: Believe me, I so wish I could. Corporate environment rules, though. It seems, from what I hear, Chrome and Firefox are harder to maintain & patch administration wise. *sigh*

Comment: @jason you could actually use [jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733475/alternative-for-nth-child-for-older-ie-browsers) to do the job for you, since you are already using the jQuery library.