# Select one class with another class with HTML/CSS for IE 6, 7, and 8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to do is make a clear div box to work cross-browser (Mozilla, Chrome, Opera, IE 9+, Safari) + IE 6, 7, and 8 like that pictured below:

http://s29.postimg.org/8hp8m56gm/5_21_2014_12_06_38_AM.jpg

I got it to work in all the other browsers except IE 6, 7, and 8.

To approach this, I utilized @potench's response found here: [How does one target IE7 and IE8 with valid CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814219/how-does-one-target-ie7-and-ie8-with-valid-css).  This was extremely helpful, however I cannot get it to work with IE 6, 7, 8 because @potench's advice only describes how to use it with selectors (which makes sense it most cases).  However, my case is different.  My logic tells me that since I am trying to create a clear div box for IE 6, 7, and 8, I need to do it with a class.  In short, use a class to select (sp?) another class.  What I tried to do was use the class `ie8` to select `transboxBody`, but this did not work:

```
.ie8 transboxBody{
    background-color: #fff;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

Instead of this, I tried to select second div element in my HTML:

```
div:second-child  {
    background-color: #fff;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

This should select this div element:

```
<div class="transboxHead">
    <img src="../_images/image">
    <h2>Header text</h2>
</div>
```

However, this did not work as it effected the div box color in Mozilla, Chrome, Opera, IE 9+, and Safari.

So in sum: is there an easier way to do this?  Can I select a class with another class?  If not, what would be the best way to approach this?

Please note that I am not interested in using Jquery for learning purposes... I want to get this to work with as clean of code possible, and having a Jquery function will add more bulk.

Here's my code...

CSS:

```
/*Zeroes out all margins*/
* {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

/*Center align website*/
#wrapper {
   width:47em;
   margin:0 auto;
   text-align:left;
}

body {
   text-align:center; /*For IE6*/
}

/*Background image for website*/
html, body {
    background-image:url("../_images/Background.jpg");
}

/*Top transparent box*/
.transboxHead {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
    opacity: 0.6;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    padding: 1em;
}

/*Body transparent box*/
.transboxBody {
    margin:30px 0px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
    border-radius:25px;
    padding: 1em;
}

.ie6 transboxBody{
    background-color: #fff;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}

/*Registartion form styling*/
.logregform li {
    margin: 10px;
    /*I added the width and height seen below to try to get it work in Chrome*/
    padding:top;
    width:220px;
    height:30px;
}

/*Center fields*/
.contact_form { 
    width:240px;  
    overflow:hidden; 
    padding:10px; 
}

/*Contact form styling*/
.contact_form ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8">    <![endif]-->

<head> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/stylesheet.css"/>
</head>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="transboxHead">
        <img src="../_images/image">
        <h2>Header text</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="centered transboxBody">
        <div class="logregform">
                <form class="contact_form">
                    <ul>
                        <li>

                        </li>
                        <li>

                        </li>
                        <li>

                        </li>
                        <li>

                        </li>
                        <li>

                        </li>
                        <li>

                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </form>     
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The child selector *is* supported by IE7 and IE8, but you're not using it anywhere in your code. You're using `:nth-child()`, which is indeed not supported in IE8 and older.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733475/alternative-for-nth-child-for-older-ie-browsers or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577674/how-to-make-internet-explorer-8-to-support-nth-child-css-element

Comment: I do not want to use Jquery @mplungjan

Comment: So read the other answers

Comment: As I said, read the answers in the links I gave that does not use jQuery - anyway you found what you needed it seems

Comment: I'm not interested in using "tricks" or "hacks" to get it done.  I want something solid.  What those comments offer are bulky and unnecessary in my opinion.  Thank you, anyways.  However, I did not solve my problem, fully.  I realized using this method effects Chrome, Firefox, etc...  So the floor is still open for answers.

Comment: don't you wanna try hack for IE than how you wanna achieve transparency in IE ?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code. You missed "." in the class.

```
.ie8 transboxBody{
background-color: #fff;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

The above css class should be written like below

```
.ie8 .transboxBody{
background-color: #fff;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

Comment: this helped a lot.  Thanks so much. One question:  Is there a way I can have this work for IE 6, 7, and 8 by placing .ie6 .ie7 .ie8 before the .transboxBody{
background-color: #fff;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
} ? 

From what I've read, I'd do this: .ie6, .ie7, .ie8, .transboxBody { -code- } ... so I would use commas to separate the classes.

Comment: You can write with comma separate. But the syntax should be like this:  .ie6 .transboxBody,.ie7 .transboxBody,.ie8 .transboxBody{-code-}

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get fall back of `rgba()` for IE's, then you are doing wrong. You are using `filter` with opacity that will affect all the text also.

You should use below code for `rgba()` background

```
    background:none;
    -ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#33ffffff,endColorstr=#33ffffff);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#33ffffff,endColorstr=#33ffffff);
    zoom: 1;
```

**this is fallback for**  `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)`

You have to change `#33ffffff` according to yours.

### [How to calculate `ARGB` for `RGBA`](http://web.archive.org/web/20131207234608/http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/)

---

Here is your code

```
.ie8 .transboxBody { 
   background:none;
   -ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4CFFFFFF,endColorstr=#4CFFFFFF);
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4CFFFFFF,endColorstr=#4CFFFFFF);
   zoom: 1;
}
```