# How to use :nth-last-child in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have this CSS below, but it doesn't work on IE8. I know that CSS3 doesn't work on IE8.

I would like to try something like `div:first-child + div + div` but it doesn't work. I think it doesn't work because of `nth-last-child()`. I can't translate `nth-last-child()` with adjacent sibling combinator (+).

```
/* one item */
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1) {
width: 100%;
}

/* two items */
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2),
div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(1) {
width: 50%;
}

/* four items */
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4),
div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3),
div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2),
div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(1) {
width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: That's because IE8 doesn't support CSS3.

Comment: see the second answer in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733475/alternative-for-nth-child-for-older-ie-browsers

Comment: @3rror404 I know that

Comment: IE8 does support `:first-child` though. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS-only solution not possible, you are dealing with browsers that are way too old. On the upside, you don't need your own script as Selectivzr does just this, or alternatively the all-in-one solution that is IE9.js (fixes a ton of other IE bugs, not just add new selectors).

Comment: I am very pleased ))))